# Eulerian paths in non-traversable graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose I have a weighted connected graph which is traversable (each vertex has even degree) and I wish to walk over all edges. Clearly any Eulerian path minimizes the total weight. What can be said about the case of non-traversable (weighted connected) graphs? Can a minimum-weight path still be found in polynomial time?

Comment: You want a path that traverses every edge _at least_ once, I suppose?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes. Sorry, I had typed that but it must have been deleted as I edited the post before submitting.

Comment: I would be surprised if it had an efficient solution. It is a variant of the travelling purchaser problem (on the line graph) but with some simplifications (like travel cost zero) and only one product.

Comment: This is the Route inspection problem a.k.a. Chinese Postman Problem. This has a polynomial time algorithm for undirected graphs and polynomial for directed graphs, but it is NP-complete for mixed graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done in polynomial time.

What we need to is find a minimum-weight set of edges to traverse twice, such that the graph with some edges doubled is traversable. Once we have that, finding an actual Eulerian path is of course easy.

The edges we need to double will form a set of paths each connecting two *odd-degree* nodes, such that each odd-degree node is the endpoint of exactly one of the path.

To find out which odd-degree nodes to connect, temporarily disregard the even-degree nodes and instead consider a graph with one edge between *each* pair of odd-degree nodes, its weight being the length of the shortest path between those nodes in the original graph.

What we need to find is then a *minimal perfect matching* in the reduced graph, which is known to have a [polynomial-time algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm#Weighted_matching).